# How do i fix this simple program? guessing game

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, joptionpane, do-while

Hello please please please can someone help me. I am writing a program where the user can enter a maximum number for a guessing game and using a random generator he/she would have to guess the number from 1-to the max number. i have done most of it but i am stuck on how to loop back the program to enter another input if user say enters a letter or anything else apart from an integer. From the "do" part is where i get confused!

```js
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class guessinggame { // class name

    public static void main(String[] args) { // main method

        String smax = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your maximum number for the Guessing Game:");
        int max = Integer.parseInt(smax);
        do {
            if (max > 10000) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Oh no! keep your choice below 10000 please.");
                smax = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter your maximum number for the Guessing Game:");
                max = Integer.parseInt(smax);
            }
        } while (max > 10000);

        int answer, guess = 0, lowcount = 0, highcount = 0, game;
        String sguess;
        Random generator = new Random();
        answer = generator.nextInt(max) + 1;

        ArrayList<String> buttonChoices = new ArrayList<String>(); // list of string arrays called buttonChoices 
        buttonChoices.add("1-" + max + " Guessing Game");

        Object[] buttons = buttonChoices.toArray(); // turning the string arrays into objects called buttons

        game = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Play or Quit?", "Guessing Game",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                null, buttons, buttonChoices.get(0));

        do {
            sguess = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("I am thinking of a number between 1 and " + max + ". Have a guess:");
            try {
                guess = Integer.parseInt(sguess);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That was not a number! ");

            }

            if (guess < answer) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That is too LOW!");
                lowcount++;

            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That is too HIGH!");
                highcount++;
            }
            break;

        } while (guess != answer);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Well Done!" + "\n---------------" + "\nThe answer was " + answer + "\nLow Guesses: " + lowcount
                + "\nHigh Guesses: " + highcount + "\n\nOverall you guessed: " + (lowcount + highcount) + " Times");

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Get the input, go into a `while(input.isNotValid) getInput` - or similar...like `do { getInput } while (input.isNotValid)`.

Comment: Dammit, this is Java, not JavaScript! There is a difference! I can't change the tag from iOS, someone else please do so so the question's grouped correctly.

Comment: i dont understand what you mean chief

Comment: Format your code so it's readable and I'll take a look at it. It's too sloppy at this point to bother with it. Address me with @Chief when your done.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils here you go bro many thanks means alot!

Comment: i would be overly grateful if there was anyway the cancel button would have looped back to the user input aswell that would be the icing on the cake.

Comment: Well, it's really easy to see now. You break from the loop the first time through.  You have the same potential risks with your other dialogues too. And I think you'd be better served to catch the exception after all the code that should be run when no exception is thrown. Then you alert them, they say OK, the loop starts over.

Comment: i dont understand how do i fix this then ? @ChiefTwoPencils

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing's first, the `break` in the last `do-while`. If you `break` without condition inside a loop; it's not a loop; it's a single-execution block.

Other than that, you should, in areas where you're validating input, follow this structure. (pseudo code so you can implement).

```
Do-While input does not equal answer
    Get input from user with dialogue

    Begin Try
        Parse user input
        If input > answer
           Notify user
        Else-If input < answer
           Notify user
    End Try
    Begin Catch Parse error
        Alert user of invalid input
    End Catch
End While
```